# WSA 10049 error with no apparent cause

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I've been trying to write a simple chat program in C++, and I've run into a socket issue. The following code is returning

Last error code was(1): 0
Last error code was(2): 0
Last error code was(3): 10049
Last error code was(4): 10022

After checking the MSDN page for WSA errors, I found that 10022 was for an invalid argument, and 10049 was trying to bind to an unavailable address. I concluded that the 10049 error was causing the 10022 error as I was trying to listen on an unbound socket.

After that, tried several different addresses to find ANY available address, including 127.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x, 0.0.0.0, none of which worked. I jumping in CMD, and saw that other processes were using these addressesCan anyone point me in the right direction to finding the root of this problem?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     long SUCCESSFUL;
     WSAData WinSockData;
     WORD DLLVERSION;

     DLLVERSION = MAKEWORD(2, 1);

     SUCCESSFUL = WSAStartup(DLLVERSION, &WinSockData);

     SOCKADDR_IN ADDRESS;
     int AddressSize = sizeof(ADDRESS);

     SOCKET sock_CONNECTION;

     const CHAR addr[15] = "127.0.0.1";
     char buffer [sizeof(in_addr)];

     printf("Last error code was(1): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

     sock_CONNECTION = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
     ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_pton(AF_INET, (const CHAR*)&addr, &buffer);
     ADDRESS.sin_family = AF_INET;
     ADDRESS.sin_port = htons(444);

     printf("Last error code was(2): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());


     bind(sock_CONNECTION, (SOCKADDR *)&ADDRESS, AddressSize);

     printf("Last error code was(3): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

     listen(sock_CONNECTION, 5);

     printf("Last error code was(4): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
     //note to self: don't use %x when referring to WSAGetLastError, returns untrue value outside WSAerror regular field
     pause();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a port above 1024?

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! Do not add unrelated tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a general note:  you need to check the return value of every function you call, and only print out the value of WSAGetLastError() if the return value indicated that the function returned an error.  Otherwise you're only going to confuse yourself by looking at error-code values that were left over from previous calls, and don't have anything to do with the most-recently-called call.  That is, instead of doing this:

```
bind(sock_CONNECTION, (SOCKADDR *)&ADDRESS, AddressSize);
printf("Last error code was(3): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
```

... you should be doing this:

```
if (bind(sock_CONNECTION, (SOCKADDR *)&ADDRESS, AddressSize) != 0)
{
    printf("bind() failed, last error code was(3): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
```

... and similar for all the other functions that you call.  (note that different functions return different values to indicate an error, so you need to read the documentation page for each function to find out the right way to test the return value for success vs. failure)

That said, I think the specific problem is here:

```
 ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_pton(AF_INET, (const CHAR*)&addr, &buffer);
```

[inet_pton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844(v=vs.85).aspx)() does not return an address; rather it returns "1 if the address was valid for the specified address family, or 0 if the address was not parseable in the specified address family, or -1 if some system error occurred (in which case errno will have been set)".  So the value that you are writing to ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr is either -1, 0, or 1; none of those are a valid address that bind() will want to use.  (Well, actually 0 could be used; see below, but the call is still wrong)

The proper way to call inet_pton() would be more like this:

```
int result = inet_pton(AF_INET, addr, &ADDRESS.sin_addr);
if (result != 1) printf("inet_pton() failed, error code %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
```

... but my suspicion is that for what you probably want to do (accept connections on any network interface) you don't need to call inet_pton() at all.  Instead, you can just set ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr to INADDR_ANY and then bind() will bind your socket in such a way that it will accept incoming TCP connections regardless of which network interface they come in on.

```
 // INADDR_ANY (aka 0) means "I don't care which network interface, accept connections on any of them"
 ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```